# Transform a list to a number composed of its elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to convert a list, for example `[1,0,1,0]` to the number `1010` (type `int`). Moreover, I'd like to do it within a function, so not using `return`. Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

```
def convert_list_of_ints_to_int( lst ):
   return reduce(lambda x, y: x*10 + y, lst)
```

Comment: +1 for a pretty cool use of reduce/lambda (which suck 99% of the time)

Comment: Functional programming much? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

```
def concat_list(inlist):
    return sum(10**pwr*elem for pwr, elem in enumerate(inlist[::-1]))
```

in verbose form

```
def concat_list(inlist):
    res = inlist[0]
    for elem in inlist[1:]:
        res=res*10+elem
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, @JonClements' comment is clearly the most pythonic answer:

```
int(''.join(map(str, some_list)))
```

Though I'd use a generator-comprehension, which is generally preferable over `map`, and is more readable:

```
int(''.join( str(num) for num in some_list ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, using `numpy`. I don't claim it is *better* than any of the other answers, but I find it cool nevertheless.

```
a = [1,0,1,0]
( a * 10**numpy.arange(len(a))[::-1] ).sum()
=> 1010
```